# Посчитать количество элементов на странице

Tags: python, selenium, тестирование

Начинаю разбираться с автотестированием на python+selenium, и все время плотно застреваю на javascript, с которым дела никогда не имела. Мне нужно посчитать непрочитанные заявки в большой таблице со всеми заявками. Общего у них то, что они имеют класс "unviewed". Я попробовала сделать так, но так мне возвращается 0.

```
def look_for_element(self):
    driver = self.driver
    b[]
try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("unviewed")
    while driver.find_element_by_class_name("unviewed") == True:
        b.append(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("unviewed"))
    print(len(b))
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('0')
    continue
```

До этого я пыталась в наглую совсем просто:

```
def look_for_element(self):
    driver = self.driver
    b[]
    b.append(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("unviewed"))
    print(len(b))
```

Аналогично я пыталась посчитать вообще все заявки, чтобы проверить что дело не в неправильном пути. И на вообще всех заявках работает также.
Код элемента любой заявки:

```
<tr class="data-row rowkey-157e2c09fd6a096b061c2baf0b1d8899 unviewed scoring_status_- odd collapsed" data-rowkey="157e2c09fd6a096b061c2baf0b1d8899">
```

Answer (score 1):

Это `while driver.find_element_by_class_name("unviewed") == True:` всегда False.

Я бы сделал просто так:

```
def look_for_element(self):
    driver = self.driver
    print len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("unviewed")))
```

Или же лучше по xpath:

```
def look_for_element(self):
    driver = self.driver
    print len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@class, 'unviewed') and @data-rowkey ]")))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!